# iOS Game Center GKScore playerID

Tags: ios, game-center, gkscore

I'm trying to save some GKScores which may have different playerIDs

ex:
I have 2 GKScore objects, score1 and score2.

```
score1 has .playerID = @"player1", .value = 10
score2 has .playerID = @"player2", .value = 12
```

Does the score gets reported to their respective playeIDs, even when @"player1" is the one signed in while submitting score2 (having playerID = @"player2")?

Answer (score 0):

playerID is read-only.

When you initialize a new score object, the playerID property is set to the identifier for the local player. If the score object was returned to your game by loading scores from Game Center, the playerID property identifies the player who recorded that score.

When reporting scores, it uses the local user.

Comment: What happens when an object of GKScore having playerID 1 is submitted when a player with playerID 2 is logged in?

Comment: The playerID of the GKScore is not used. The ID of the logged in user is used when reporting scores.

Comment: So in case of a network error, do i need to check the playerID of the GKScore, which is saved for submission, against the playerID currently logged in?

Comment: No, you shouldn't have to do any checking - but that is a good question. I have not seen the specific case you are describing and Apple does not document it.

Comment: But if we don't check the playerID of the GKScore and the playerID currently logged in, then some other player's score, which had been saved for submission later because of network error, will be submitted when another user is logged in.